Using parentheses inside a foreach loop, with parse=true
I am trying to perform some calculations in a foreach loop in tikz, using parentheses.
The expected output is a bunch of vertical lines.
The solution here does not work in this case: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717048/319072
Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725133/319072
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach[parse=true] \Vt in {0,0.75*(0+0.2),...,0.75*5}{
    \draw (\Vt,0) -- (\Vt,1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\draw[xstep=.2*.75, ystep=0] (0,0) grid (5*.75,1); or \draw[xscale=.75, xstep=.2, ystep=0] (0,0) grid (5,1);

If you read the documentation of the parse key you'll read the following in pgfmanual.pdf section 88 (as of writing this on page 1005; emphasis by me):

If this key is set to true the upper bound in the loop will be fed into \pgfmathparse.

So this is expected behaviour. While using LaTeX the easiest (imho) solution to this is to use \fpeval on your second element:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[parse=true] \Vt in {0,\fpeval{0.75*(0+0.2)},...,0.75*5}{
    \draw (\Vt,0) -- (\Vt,1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

If you want to stick to pgf/TikZ solutions 100% the alternative is to use the evaluate key of \foreach:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[parse=true,evaluate=\Vt] \Vt in {0,0.75*(0+0.2),...,0.75*5}{
    \draw (\Vt,0) -- (\Vt,1);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Both yield


Thank you for your response. My apologies if I haven't read the doc thoroughly enough. I didn't even consider to read the parse section.

@Jasper The doc is huge, but is is very helpful. There is also an online version at https://tikz.dev whose search function however is a bit strange sometimes.
